# JavaFX Groups that accept specific object types

Tags: javafx

Is there a way in JavaFX to make a class that extends `Group` and limit it to accepting only `Shape` objects as children?

Comment: Override the method that accepts Nodes to Shapes

Comment: @Strven: You cannot override a method with a implementation that uses different parameter types (except for type erasure) and even if you could you shouldn't, since it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Thanks Steve.  @Fabian, indeed I could not override the getchildren().add(...) method. Thanks for link. I'll read up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider creating a wrapper class instead of a subclass. Something along the lines of

```
public class ShapeGroup {

    private final Group group = new Group() ;

    public void addShape(Shape s) {
        group.getChildren().add(s);
    }

    public void removeShape(Shape s) {
        group.getChildren().remove(s);
    }

    // other methods you want to expose, implemented similarly...

    public Parent asParent() {
        return group ;
    }
}
```

And now you can use this as follows:

```
ShapeGroup shapeGroup = new ShapeGroup();
shapeGroup.addShape(new Circle(50, 50, 20));
shapeGroup.addShape(new Rectangle(20, 20, 30, 30));
// ...
Scene scene = new Scene(shapeGroup.asParent());
// etc..
```

Comment: Thanks James_D. Yes, that is the solution I was thinking about, but was hoping for another way to avoid writing  wrappers for all methods I could possibly use from Group :/ . Having started using type parameters recently, I am not sure why Java does not have this for Groups. I might be wrong, but it sounds like a good idea...

Comment: Too many type parameters would clutter the API and make it too complex. There are very few methods in `Group` that are not inherited from `Parent`,  and `Parent` only exposes the child nodes as an unmodifiable list, so there isn't much you need to write for a wrapper in this case.

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks!